# Why is it showing like "Type range cannot be used for int" in C-PLEX programming?

Tags: matlab, types, integer, range, cplex

```
forall(i in nbus,j in tavail,k in nport)
  {ct3:if(soc[k][j]<=0.3&&pt[i][j]<pl[i][j])
     { pbatch[j][k]-(0.7-soc[k][j])*100000==0;}
      else
      {pbatch[j][k]==0;}}
```

pbatch is a decision variable. When I assign a value to pbatch, it is showing that I cannot use the type range for int.

Expecting to remove the error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, is soc a decision variable too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
range nbus=1..1;
range tavail=1..3;
range nport=1..4;

int soc[k in nport][j in tavail]=rand(2);
int pl[i in nbus][j in tavail]=rand(4);
int pt[i in nbus][j in tavail]=rand(10);


dvar float+ pbatch[tavail][nport];



subject to
{

forall(i in nbus,j in tavail,k in nport)
  {ct3:if(soc[k][j]<=0.3&&pt[i][j]<pl[i][j])
     { pbatch[j][k]-(0.7-soc[k][j])*100000==0;}
      else
      {pbatch[j][k]==0;}}
      
    }
```

works fine

Comment: Actually I have  given the values of SOC,pl and pt as input datas. Then how can I write like this?